# Let f be an automorphism of some integral domain R. Show that f admits a unique extension to an automorphism of the quotient field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Quotient Field (field of fractions) - Let R be an integral domain. Then the quotient field of R is the set (field) of all elements a/b for all a,b in R.

Could anyone help me please prove this?

Thank you,

Daniele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ can be extended to an automorphism $\tilde{f}$ of the quotient field of $R$, then we must have
$$ \tilde{f}(r)\tilde{f}\Big(\frac{1}{r}\Big)=f(1)=1$$
for all $0\neq r\in R$, hence $\tilde{f}(\frac{1}{r})=\frac{1}{\tilde{f}(r)}=\frac{1}{f(r)}$. This implies that we must have
$$ \tilde{f}\Big(\frac{r}{s}\Big)=\tilde{f}(r)\tilde{f}\Big(\frac{1}{s}\Big)=\frac{f(r)}{f(s)}$$

This shows that the extension, if it is well-defined, is unique. So all that's left to show is that $\tilde{f}$ as defined above is in fact an automorphism of the field of fractions.

Comment: Thank you for this. How do you then show that it is an automorphism?

Comment: You have to show that (i) $\tilde{f}$ is well-defined (i.e. doesn't depend on the choice of $r$ and $s$ to represent $\frac{r}{s}$, (ii) $\tilde{f}$ is a ring homomorphism, and (iii) $\tilde{f}$ has an inverse. All three should be straightforward, using what you know about $f$.

Comment: To show i), do you say that we define to be equivalent a/b=c/d if ad=cb?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: (let f mean squiggly line f). To show that it is a homomorphism, can you just show that f(r/s)=f(rs^-1)=f(r)f(1/s)=f(r)f(s^-1) as you showed above.

Comment: Can I ask, why is it true that     f̃ (r)f̃ (1/r)=f(1)=1

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more: $f(\frac{r}{s}+\frac{u}{v})=f(\frac{r}{s})+f(\frac{u}{v})$, and $f(\frac{r}{s}\frac{u}{v})=f(\frac{r}{s})f(\frac{u}{v})$.

Comment: To be a ring homomorphism, it must be true that $f(r)f(\frac{1}{r})=f(r\cdot \frac{1}{r})=f(1)=1$.

Comment: Yes, that is true for f, but how do you know that it is true for f(line)

Comment: Finally, how do you show that f(line) has an inverse?

Comment: It's true for $\tilde{f}$ because $\tilde{f}$ is supposed to be a ring homomorphism. As for the inverse, use the fact that $f$ has an inverse $g$, and extend $g$ to $\tilde{g}$ just as for $f$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to proove the following:

> **Universal property.** If $A$ is an integral ring, $K$ is a field and $f:A\hookrightarrow K$ is an injective ring morphism, then there exists a unique field morphism $\overline{f}:\textrm{Frac}(A)\hookrightarrow K$ such that $f=\overline{f}\circ i$, where $i : A\hookrightarrow\textrm{Frac}(A)$ is the inclusion.

**Proof.** $f=\overline{f}\circ i$ imposes that $\overline{f}(a/b)=f(a)/f(b)$. The only thing to do is to show that $\overline{f}(a/b)$ does not depends on the representant chosen for $a/b$. $\Box$

This result boils down to the wanted property when taking $K=\textrm{Frac}(A)$.

Comment: The well-definedness of $\;\overline f\;$ in your "proof" of the universal property is, imo, the very salt of the this whole question, as simple as it really is. Using universal properties can be tough for a beginner as the OP seems to be ( the question is elementary), yet I like using that stuff in abstract algebra. +1